# VLookup Macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook with two worksheets.  Worksheet A has the several names in it with each name in a different column and Worksheet B contains the same names that are in worksheet A and a second column containing dates.
Example:

```
Worksheet A.       Worksheet B.

Name.              Name.     Dates
Sean               Jake      11/13/15
Jake               Sean      10/11/14
Tom.               Chris     12/12/15
```

What I am trying to do is set a macro that calls VLookup and passes the name from the name column in Worksheet A as a search parameter on Worksheet B.  once the name is found on Worksheet B, it returns the date.  Currently I am manually having this data pulled by hard coding the following vlookup in a column on Worksheet A.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'Worksheet B'!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Any suggestions and help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you both for your help!  The code below works great Jeeped the only issue that i have is what to do if the cell that I want the value returned to is on the opposite end of the worksheet.  In the code below the date will be returned in column 2, but what if I wanted the value to be returned in column 14?

Comment: [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) are used when the return value is to the right of the lookup column. To return values from column left of the lookup column, use the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) paired with the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca). See my edit below for an example.

Comment: Thanks  again for providing me with a working solution!  This works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use worksheet functions within VBA. This macro takes advantage of them by returning the values they discover into the appropriate cells.

```
Sub auto_VLOOKUP()
    Dim rw As Long, wsB As Worksheet
    Set wsB = Worksheets("Worksheet B")
    With Worksheets("Worksheet A")
        For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If CBool(Application.CountIf(wsB.Columns(1), .Cells(rw, 1).Value)) Then
                ' VLOOKUP is typically used to return data from the right of the lookup column
                .Cells(rw, 2) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 1).Value, wsB.Columns("A:B"), 2, False)
                ' INDEX/MATCH function pairs are used to wider scope
                .Cells(rw, 3) = Application.Index(wsB.Columns("N"), Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 1).Value, wsB.Columns("A"), 0))
            End If
        Next rw
        .Cells(2, 2).Resize(rw - 2, 1).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    End With
    Set wsB = Nothing
End Sub
```

You will have to edit the worksheet names and adjust any columns that are not the same as the ones you provided in your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't vlookup, but it will get the results you want.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
    Dim c As Range, FndC As Range, shRng As Range


    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set shRng = sh.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
    With ws
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rws, 1))
    End With
    For Each c In Rng.Cells

        Set FndC = shRng.Find(what:=c, lookat:=xlWhole)

        If Not FndC Is Nothing Then
            c.Offset(0, 1) = FndC.Offset(0, 1)
        Else: c.Offset(0, 1) = "Not Found"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```